# Google Reseller APIs: how to get customer Billing data

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-reseller-api

can anyone please explain how to extract billing information from a Reseller's Perspective? i mean i want to get -if possible- a general billing file and also a more detailed report-let's say for each customer. Is that possible? 
Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Customers: get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/customers/get) method.

You need to supply **customerId** which is actually a customer's unique identifier or primary domain name. If successful you will get a 200 response code and a response body just like below.

```
{
  "kind": "reseller#customer",
  "customerId": string,
  "customerDomain": string,
  "postalAddress": {
    "kind": "customers#address",
    "contactName": string,
    "organizationName": string,
    "locality": string,
    "region": string,
    "postalCode": string,
    "countryCode": string,
    "addressLine1": string,
    "addressLine2": string,
    "addressLine3": string
  },
  "phoneNumber": string,
  "alternateEmail": string,
  "resourceUiUrl": string,
  "customerDomainVerified": boolean
}
```